# Index Numpy array dimensions with tuple

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array such as `arr = np.arange(16).reshape(2,2,2,2)`

I want to dynamically access `arr[:, dim2, dim3]`, when I have `(dim2, dim3)` as a tuple. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you thinking of a case where you know the dimensions of your array in advance, or are you trying to think of a method that would work even if you didn't know, say, the number of dimensions in the array?

Comment: @jjramsey The latter, I'll make that clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this if the number of dimensions might not be the same for your array:

```py
some_tuple = (dim2, dim3) # Could be (dim2, dim3, ..., dimN)

arr[(slice(None),) + some_tuple]
```

In this *particular* case, `(slice(None),) + some_tuple` is the same as `(slice(None), dim2, dim3)`. `slice(None)` is more or less equivalent to "`:`", but it can be used in more places than "`:`". Notice that I put `slice(None)` in a single-element tuple (i.e. `(slice(None),)`) so that I can add it to `some_tuple`. Notice as well that there's a comma after `slice(None)`, i.e., I *don't* just write `(slice(None))` without a comma. It won't work without the extra comma.

Comment: Nice answer. Alternatively `arr[(slice(None), *some_tuple)]` could also be an option, this way you avoid creating a tuple

Answer (score 0):

```py
some_tuple = (dim2, dim3)

arr[:, some_tuple[0], some_tuple[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a general way to do this, especially if I have a long tuple?